# How to match field value based on condition using MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have tried for match same value based on if else condition using MongoDB but value is not match.

```
var abc = false;
db.getCollection('deviceHistory').find({ 
     $match: { 
        $cond: {
            if: { 
                $eq: [abc, false ] 
            }, 
            then: {
                'purchaserId':ObjectId("5d47bd2f005d3e192c3e82de")
            }, 
            else:{
                'sellerId':ObjectId("5d47bd2f005d3e192c3e82de")
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: You should  use Aggregation framework. See here how can you use `$cond`: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/#example
If you didn't get the things. Just provide some sample data and the expected output.

Comment: In Your Link 1 field and diff value but
I need 1 value and diff filed in $match that reason i have written this code

Comment: Okay  fine, can you add some sample data and expected output in your question.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [$or](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) operator:

```
db.getCollection('deviceHistory').find({ 
  $or : [
    { abc: false, purchaserId: ObjectId("5d47bd2f005d3e192c3e82de") },
    { abc: true, sellerId: ObjectId("5d47bd2f005d3e192c3e82de") }
  ]
})
```